# Azure Search Service top Value more than 1000

Tags: c#, azure, azure-sql-database, azure-cognitive-search

Iam getting `documents` via Search Documents (Azure Search Service REST API).
The problem is the the maximum value of `top` is `1000` shown [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/searchservice/search-documents).

Now Iam testing the performance of getting `70000` documents which means I have to send a request `70` times.

I do get the `70000` documents without any problems because of the `continuation token`. But sadly it's very slow..

Here some examples:

```
Number of documents: 70000
Documents per request: 1000 
One Searchservice-Request with 1000 requests takes on average: 343,986301369863ms (0,343986301369863 seconds)
number of requests in total: 70
The whole requests took: 25168ms (25 seconds)

Number of documents: 70000
Documents per request: 500
One Searchservice-Request with 500 requests takes on average: 242,472602739726ms (0,242472602739726 seconds)
number of requests in total: 140
The whole requests took: 35499ms (35 seconds)

Number of documents: 70000
Documents per request: 250
One Searchservice-Request with 250 requests takes on average: 189,465753424658ms (0,189465753424658 seconds)
number of requests in total: 280
The whole requests took: 55495ms (55 seconds)

Number of documents: 70000
Documents per request: 50
One Searchservice-Request with 50 requests takes on average: 151,955357142857ms (0,151955357142857 seconds)
number of requests in total: 1400
The whole requests took: 222033ms (222 seconds)
```

You can clearly see, that the more `documents` I get per `request`, the faster the whole `request` is done.

My question is: Is it possible to get more then 1000 `documents` per request / set the `top` value higher than `1000` to tune the performance?

Could the Azure-Team unlock something like this for me?
Or do I just have to live with the timeloss?

Thank you very much.

Comment: Can you elaborate a bit on your scenario? Are you trying to export data from an index? Also, when measuring latency, where was the client running? On premises? In the same Azure region as your search service? Etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> My question is: Is it possible to get more then 1000 documents per
>   request / set the top value higher than 1000 to tune the performance?

No, it is not possible to get more than 1000 documents per request. This restriction is at a global level and can't be customized at service level.